# How can I set the liquibase.properties path ignore the OS?

Tags: liquibase

I want to put my liquibase.properties to another local folder. such as: c:\opt\liquibase\config

And I hope the path can ignore the OS.

So in my pom.xml,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <propertyFile>\opt\liquibase\config</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But it doesn't work, I must add the prefix "C:" to path.

Is there any way to set the path but ignore the OS?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use absolute paths at all, but use a path relative to the root of the project or the POM. If you would like to reference a path that is outside the project, use an environment variable to set the path and allow each user to set the value.

If you hard code an absolute path into the POM, you make it difficult to use for anyone else using it.